# Linear subspaces generated by basis elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on the following problem.

Let $x_1, ... , x_n$ be a basis of a vector space $V$. For $k = 1, ... n$ let $M_k$ be the linear subspace $V$ generated by $x_1, ... x_k$ and let $M_0 = {0}$ (the zero vector).

For each $k = 1, ... n$ choose $y_k$ such that $y_k \in M_k$ and $y_k \notin M_{k-1}$ and define $y_k = a_kx_k + z_k$ where $z_k \in M_{k-1}$.

Prove that $y_1, ...y_n$ is a basis of V.

Hint: Argue first that the $a_k$ must be non-zero and then that the $y_k$ are linearly independent.

Thoughts: I know that if $a_k = 0$ then $y_k \in M_{k-1}$, a contradiction, but I am having difficulty showing that the $y_k$ are linearly indepedent.

Comment: It's not clear what is z_k. Or rather, the definition of y_k

Comment: @iPe $z_k$ is an element of $M_{k-1}$ , $y_k$ is unique to $M_k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the minimal number such that $a_k=0$. Then $y_k=z_k\in M_{k-1}$, contradicting the requirement $y_k\in M_k\setminus M_{k-1}$.

So the $a_k$'s are non-zero. We will now show that $y_1,...,y_n$ are linearly independent. This would be enough, since the dimension of the space is $n$.

Assume that $y_1,...y_k$ are dependent. We have $x_k=a_k^{-1}( y_k-z_k)$, implying that $x_k$ is a linear combination of $y_1,...,y_{k-1}$, hence a linear combination of $x_1,...,x_{k-1}$, a contradiction to the fact that $x_1,...,x_n$ are linearly independent.